# How to make a multiple launcher in xfce4-panel (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xfce-panel

I remember an option to create a launcher in XFCE (Xubuntu) that's divided into four corners, each with its own application. Is there still an option like that? I used to run that with Xubuntu 14.04, and now I have Xubuntu core 16.04, So I'm not sure whether they removed the feature, trimmed it down in the "core" edition (so it's a package installation matter), or I'm just too blind to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if not already installed run `sudo apt-get install xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin` to install.

Right clicking on your panel will bring up `panel menu` > `panel` > `add new items`. In the add new items window scroll down and left click `quicklauncher` left click `add`. Then you can customize the quicklauncher.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, exactly what I was looking for, googling in search for it never mentioned this package name